# How to create a filename with a trailing period in Windows?

Tags: python, c, windows, filenames

How does one work with filenames that end in a period in Python? According to MSDN's site, such filenames are valid in Windows, but whenever I try to create one in Python, it removes the final period. I even tried creating a raw file descriptor with os.open, but it still removes the period.

For example, this will create a file simply named '`test`'

```
os.open('test.', os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY, 0777)
```

Edit: [Here is the exact quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)

> About spaces and dots in filenames and directories.   The limits are
>   in the windows shell -- not in Windows or NT.   Using 'bash', you can
>   create files with spaces (or dots), both, at the beginning and end of
>   a filename.  You can then list and open those files in explorer, and
>   you can 'list' them in the shell (cmd.exe), but you won't necessarily
>   be able to open them from the shell (especially trailing spaces and
>   dots).

Comment: Can you please provide a link to MSDN article that says filenames ending with period are valid. This is what I see in wikipedia: "The Win32 API strips trailing space and period (full-stop) characters from filenames, except when UNC paths are used" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)

Comment: Have you tried creating a file with trailing period in file name in windows ? It won't be created. After the rename it is shown as 'test' instead of 'test.' I believe it is to do with windows not python.

Comment: @Antimony, you may need to use pywin32 and CreateFile directly to make that work.  It could be that MS is filtering the filename on the way into the underlying system call when using open().

Comment: It wasn't necessary to accept my answer if it didn't really work. I just tried it for myself right now, and Python wouldn't create the file for me but Cygwin had no trouble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Apparently, passing a normal filename will strip the period even when calling the Win API directly from C. In order to create the weird filenames, you must use the `\\?\` prefix (this also disables relative paths and slash conversion).

```
open('\\\\?\\C:\\whatever\\test.','w')
```

It's ugly and nonportable, but it works.

Comment: This is exactly the difference between Win32 API and NTFS capabilities. Win32 API separates filenames in name + extension and has lots of handling for that, while NTFS doesnt really care. The `\\?\` sequence disables the special handling in most Win32 APIs and causes them to transfer the filenames to the NTFS API more directly, so you can do things that the Win32 API normally prevents.

As a normal application, you are supposed to play nice and conform to Win32.

Answer (score 7):

The `\\?\` syntax also works with `cmd.exe`:

```
dir>"\\?\C:\whatever\test."
```