# Why is directory name which contains dot(s) in the end is treated as a directory even if doesn't exists using File object in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a directory which contains several files and directories. I am writing a small java program which displays the files present in a the directory supplied as a parameter.

The problem I am facing is when I append dot(s) after a directory name, it is being treated as existing even if the directory is not present. To further clarify, suppose I have a directory named "abc" which exists. It works fine when I enter "abc". But when I enter the directory name as "abc...", even then also the directory is being treated as it exists. I want to avoid it. I am creating a FIle object using

```
File directory = new File( fileName );
if ( directory.exists() ) {
     // do something
}
```

Any suggestions how can I avoid it?

Comment: For each file name that you want to find, replace "..." for "". Is better to split each string by the 3 last character... is they are "..." then replace.

Comment: This happens for any number of dots which I enter after the directory name. I want that if the exact named directory is not found, then it should return false.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: ok sry, then only use substring(-i), when you found a not dot character stop, and then split the string, because you know now the number of dot in the end of the filename.

Comment: Works fine for me. `/test` exists, `/test...` doesn't exists.

Comment: @AaronDigulla : WIndows 7.

Comment: Works NOT fine form me :/ `directory hello... (hello...) exists? true`. OS is win7 64bit and java 1.7.0_21

Comment: @S.D. It gives that the file exists in my case on Windows 7 - 64 bit. For "abc" as well as for "abc.."

Comment: @TheRock So, windows have a weird path resolution. Implementations of `File` are OS specific. Windows allows many _magic_ characters in file names.

Comment: It seems that windows interprets `hello` and `hello...` as the same file or directory. It is not only a java problem (File#exists() queries the attribute from FileSystem witch provides windows native functions) but even if on a commad prompt, after executing the commad `mkdir hello` the command `mkdir hello...` will fail with a message saying that the file or directory already exists

Comment: @A4L Yes. I just created a folder `test...` on windows, and its created as `test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to Java, it's a Windows thing: Trailing dot(s) are removed from file and folder names. [Even C/C++ programs can't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203594/34088).

As a workaround, try to [use the prefix `\\?\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203594/34088):

```
File dir = new File( "\\\\?\\" + path );
```

But this will disable a lot of other things like relative paths and slash conversion.

Related answers:

- [How to create a filename with a trailing period in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681207/how-to-create-a-filename-with-a-trailing-period-in-windows)
- MSDN [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)
- [Why doesn't Explorer let you create a file whose name begins with a dot?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/14/8389268.aspx)