# Why does this java function not indicate that filepath is invalid

Tags: java, windows, nio, java-io

I'm trying to check a user entered file path is valid for the OS, and I thought this could be achieved with Paths.get(filePath) so I wrote this simple function

```
 public static boolean isValidFilename(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            Paths.get(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch (InvalidPathException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but whilst on Windows 8 it will successfully return false for

```
c:\File::
```

it will not for

```
c:\File..
```

Is this a bug, or misunderstanding on my part

Comment: You shall try this making OS neutral & pick the separator as per the OS.

Comment: The code is OS neutral, these are just test cases for when using it on Windows

Comment: Don't understand why someone has tried to close this question, f course it is about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a misunderstanding on your part. A colon is not a legal filename character in Windows, but a period '.' is.

The second file is valid.... it's the same file as `C:/File..`. (i.e. `C://File..` and `C:/File..` are the same location)

Edit: See this question here: [How to create a filename with a trailing period in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681207/how-to-create-a-filename-with-a-trailing-period-in-windows)

I have tried it in my system and unfortunately my results are mixed.... still the above answers are good reading....

Edit2: I have run the following code, and it works for me now:

```
        File file = new File("\\\\?\\C:/Temp/File..");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write("Foo".getBytes());
        fos.close();
```

It appears that the `\\?\` construct works in `java.io.File`, but not in `java.nio.file.Path`

If you print out the exception you also get more of an idea of what the problem is.....

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 7: C:/File::
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:194)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:165)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:89)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:106)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:267)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:95)
```

Comment: @rolfi but if I try and create such a file in Windows explorer it removes the periods ?

Comment: That's a bug in Windows explorer.... it thinks it's smarter than you and it is looking for an extension on a file, so it does not want you to do that.

Comment: Sorry the / in one example and the // in another example was a mistype to add confusion, it should just be C:\ in both examples

Comment: Huh, I'm double-checking the trailing-dots in Windows... odd. I cannot write to a file and keep the dots after it....

Comment: Its wierd I went into DOS, and if I tried to create C:\Fred: it gives an error, if I try and create C:\Fred.. it doesnt complain but actually creates C:\Fred, and if I then try to create C:\Fred... it complains the file already exists

Comment: hmm so in sumary it is valid syntax in the os (lets call it the kernel) but the ui (either windows or Dos shell) makes it very difficult to achieve, so might be just as well not let users do it so they don't get confused. But because Javas method is based on the OS rather than the UI Id have to add this additional check with some custom pattern matching code

Comment: That appears to be the bottom line, yes. I have looked around and I don't see a way to force the trailing '.' from Java, it does not accept the `\\?\` syntax .....

Comment: Actually I cannot allow user to specify as if I give this path to File.mkdirs() it fails so when I come to actually save the chnages they get an error !

Comment: See my update.... it appears there is a work-around... interesting problem. note that Windows will treat trailing spaces in the same way as it treats trailing periods.....

Comment: So the //? syntax allows you to create a File with the dots kept using file.createNewFile(), I don't understand it but it works, however the //? syntax is not understood by file.mkdirs() it prevents file being created. This is all very inconsistent think Im going to disallow user form entering such a filename and maybe raise an rfe with Oracle. Marked your question as right as it has at least allowed me to make some sense of this.

Comment: I agree that this is inconsistent and confusing. I have friends involved with non-Oracle Java implementations and I will challenge them with this one as well.... it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your results seem to be ok.

`c://File..` is a valid filename in windows, and although I can't find any documentation about it, the two `..` seems to be handled in a special way - it is just stripped from the name, so `file..` is the same as `file` or even `file.....`. It's probably some interaction with how windows treats file extensions.

`c:/File::` is not, since you can't have a `:` in a filename
 (see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx)